# Maths - How to plot a course to a point with constrained final velocity?

Tags: math, optimization, cubic

First of all a disclaimer: I'm posting this question here even if I realize it is quite maths heavy, because I have trouble figuring out on what other site it could belong.

I'm writing a 2d spaceships game where the player will have to select the ship's destination and a course will be automatically plotted.

Along with this, I'm offering various options to control the ship's acceleration while it gets there. All these options have to do with the target velocity at the destination.

One option is to select the desired destination and velocity vector, in which case the program will use cubic interpolation, since starting and target coordinates and velocity are available.

Another option is to just select the destination point, but let the game calculate the final velocity vector. This is done through quadratic interpolation (ie. acceleration is constant).

I would like to introduce another option: let the player select the destination and the maximum absolute value of the velocity vector, as in

```
sqrt( vf_x^2 + vf_y^2 ) <= Vf_max
```

I take I shall use a 3rd order polynomial to model the course in this case, but I'm having a pretty hard time figuring out the coefficients, since I miss one equation for each coordinate (the one given by velocity at destination). Furthermore, I'm confused as to how I should use the `Vf_max` constraint to help me figure out the missing coefficients.

I suspect it could be an optimization problem, but I'm quite ignorant about this topic.

Can anybody help me find a solution or point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Is this in two or three spatial dimensions?

Comment: Two dimentions (will edit)

Comment: I find it not clear what you need. Do you want just a path, (the curve)? Or do you want the speed at every point also? Can't you use [a (quadratic) Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), they're very easy to use. Or maybe the arc of a circle? You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Does acceleration has to be constant?

Comment: Actually, I believe that plotting it would also give the velocity at each point. Anyhow the problem with Beziers is they need you to provide the equivalent of the final velocity vector (it is in fact a form of polynomial interpolation). Here we only have the **maximum length** of said vector, so no cigar...